# Determining if drug is generic or brand using NDC

Tags: openfda

Is there a way to determine if a drug is generic or brand by passing in an NDC (National Drug Code) to the drug label endpoint (https://api.fda.gov/drug/label)?

Comment: Dear curious_george (nice CD by the way), please provide more information, so that casual bystanders are able to help you, for example: What is a NDC, what endpoint are you talking about? Check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Most likely, NDC if for "National Drug Code" and the endpoint mentioned is [api.fda.gov/drug/label](https://open.fda.gov/drug/label/). By the way, there exists [FDA list](https://www.fda.gov/drugs/developmentapprovalprocess/howdrugsaredevelopedandapproved/approvalapplications/abbreviatednewdrugapplicationandagenerics/ucm126389.htm) of the so called _authorized_ generics.

Answer (score 2):

The page that [@Stanislav Kralin's comment links to](https://www.fda.gov/drugs/developmentapprovalprocess/howdrugsaredevelopedandapproved/approvalapplications/abbreviatednewdrugapplicationandagenerics/ucm126389.htm) contains a link to the [Orange Book page](https://www.fda.gov/Drugs/InformationOnDrugs/ucm129662.htm), which provides downloads for ANDA (Abbreviated New Drug Application, i.e. Generics) data and the Orange book itself. This should get you at least to 80% of the solution.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a web service so that I wouldn't have to house and refresh the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helpful strategy outlined in [this post](https://forums.ohdsi.org/t/how-to-determine-whether-a-drug-is-brand-or-generics/5745/5) that entails using the following steps to determine if a given NDC is brand or generic:

1. Use the https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/api-RxNorm.getNDCProperties.html endpoint to find the RXCUI for the NDC
2. Pass the RXCUI to the https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/api-RxNorm.getRxConceptProperties.html endpoint in order to find the associated RxNorm Term Type (TTY) which can be used to indicate brand/generic
3. If the TTY is one of the following: `'BN', 'SBDC', 'SBDF', 'SBDG', 'SBD', 'BPCK'` then it is likely a brand name drug, otherwise it's likely a generic.

Here is the appendix detailing the various TTY values: https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm/docs/2018/appendix5.html